# Combine JsonElement addProperty() into one method

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm working with [JsonElements](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html?com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and its `addProperty` method(s).  A JsonElement has 4 overloaded `addProperty` methods which I'd like to compress down into one to make it easier to add properties.  This is what I've written up to start, and I'm realizing that the tricky part is going to be figuring out if a string is a `Number`.

Any thoughts on how to improve this method?

```
public JsonElementBuilder addProperty(final String property, final Object value)
{

if (parent instanceof JsonObject) {

        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            ((JsonObject) parent).addProperty(property, (Boolean)value);            
        } else if (value instanceof Character) {
            ((JsonObject) parent).addProperty(property, (Character)value);
        } else if (value instanceof Number) {
            ((JsonObject) parent).addProperty(property, (Number)value);
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            if (isInteger((String)value))
            {
                ((JsonObject) parent).addProperty(property, (Number)value);
            } else {
                ((JsonObject) parent).addProperty(property, (String)value);
            }
        }
    }

private boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical scenario where subtype polymorphism helps. Do the following

```
 interface I {
   void do();
 }

 class A implements I { void do() { doA() } ... }
 class B implements I { void do() { doB() } ... }
 class C implements I { void do() { doC() } ... }
```

Then you can simply call do() on this.

If you are not free to change A, B, and C, you could apply the visitor pattern to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can yo explain why you want to do that? *Overloaded* methods, like you call them, is called [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), and it´s just a great Java feature that precisely allows you to avoid that kind of code into your methods.

You can make a single call for all the different classes, and Java does the selection of the correct method consuming less resources than your `if ... else` code...

Thanks to polymorphism -and btw also thanks to inheritance- you can do this:

```
//Many different types...
boolean boolProp = true;
char charProp = 'a';
int intProp = 12;
double dblProp = 1.50;
String strProp = "Polymorphism rocks!";

//One method name for all types...
jsonElement.addProperty("prop1", boolProp);
jsonElement.addProperty("prop2", charProp);
jsonElement.addProperty("prop3", intProp);
jsonElement.addProperty("prop4", dblProp);
jsonElement.addProperty("prop5", strProp);
```

So... why the hell do you want to write yourself a method that does something that Java can do itself without any effort and much more efficiently?